# Some icons are broken in the application menu

Tags: icons, xfce, debian

I am using Xfce-4.10 on Debian 7. But I found some icons are missing (and only "x"'s appear) in the application menu. Take `ipython3` as an example. Here's the `ipython3.desktop`:

```
# If you want ipython3 to appear in a linux app launcher ("start menu"), install this by doing:
# sudo desktop-file-install ipython3.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Enhanced interactive Python shell
Exec=ipython3
GenericName[en_US]=IPython3
GenericName=IPython3
Icon=ipython3
Name[en_US]=ipython3
Name=ipython3
Categories=Development;Utility;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

The theme is installed (currently `tango-icon-theme`, but other themes don't work either).
The icon file is at `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/ipython3.svg`. It can be displayed in an image viewer.

Reinstalling `ipython3` doesn't help. I also tried to replace the `ipython3.svg` with some other normal icon files (`libreoffice-calc.svg`, for example). This doesn't help either.

Any ideas to bring the icons back? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor/
```

as root in order to refresh the icons cache. It may be also performed for another directories containing the icon themes (with `index.theme` files).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet I'm using on peppermint;

```
for i in $(find /usr/share/icons/ -maxdepth 1 -type d); do sudo rm -f $i/.icon-theme.cache; sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -t -i $i; done

for i in $(find ~/.icons -maxdepth 1 -type d); do sudo rm -f $i/.icon-theme.cache; sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -t -i $i; done
```

You can easily save the code part to a file, like "regeniconcache", to whatever directory you want, and then make it executable:

```
chmod 755 ~/regeniconcache
```

and then put it into the user-executable scripts folder by:

```
sudo ln -sf ~/regeniconcache /usr/sbin/regeniconcache
```

from the terminal
Every time you notice that some widget complains that there's an icon cache file missing, you can simply type

```
regeniconcache
```

into the terminal and press enter, and the entire icon cache will be regenerated.